# How to show a div after page loads in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Hi I have a Laravel Blade template where I built a search function and I want to load a div after the page has reloaded, when I submit the form. Otherwise when the page loads with the results, the results don't show. I want the Javascript to execute while on the page (hide the div), and then when the page refreshes then the div must become visible.

My HTML form is:

```
<form action="" class="search-form" method="GET" onsubmit="showDiv();">
    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Search" required>
    <button class="search-btn" type="submit"><i class="flaticon-026-search"></i></button>
  </form>
```

And the div I want to show after page load is:

```
<div id="hideDiv" style="display:none">
  @foreach($locations as $location)
    @foreach($location->landmark as $landmark)
       <p>{{$landmark->name}}</p>
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function showDiv() {
   var div = document.getElementById("hideDiv");
   if (div.style.display == 'none') {
     div.style.display = '';
   }
   else {
     div.style.display = 'block';
   }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

Comment: No not really, I want the Javascript to execute while on the page, and then when the page refreshes then the div must become visible

Comment: You can set a variable in `localStorage` at first page load and then verify if it exists on further page loads based on which you will show/hide your div. Also you can use cookies. It's your choice.

Comment: Are you trying to show the div when the `$locations` has value and hide it when `$locations` is null?

Comment: The location gets typed typed in the searchbox and retrieves the landmarks. But the results of the landmarks already show when I open the page, so when I type the location it just minimises the search results to those with the linked location. I dont want the div to view when I load the page at first, only after I have enetered the location value and clicked on 'submit'  @ab_ab

Answer (score 0):

Write window.onload = showDiv; before your function

Comment: div.style.display = ''; replace with div.style.display = 'block';

Comment: no... when I add window.onload = showDiv; before the function, then the div shows. When I add widow.onload = function... then the div shows as well. I don't want the div to show when I go on the page, but once I submit the button I want the div to show after the page has reloaded.

Comment: if you dont wanna shoe the div at any load but only on submit you have to use php. add `<?php if(array_key_exist('submit',$_GET){echo "<script type='text/javascript'>showDiv()<script>" ?>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one submit button on same page than you can use like bellow (not tested, just try to suggest)

```
@if (Request::isMethod('post'))
 <div id="hideDiv" style="display:none">
   @foreach($locations as $location)
     @foreach($location->landmark as $landmark)
       <p>{{$landmark->name}}</p>
    @endforeach
   @endforeach
 </div>
@endif
```

PS: try to identify ispostback event in Page or Javascript which one is preferable.